# Sequence planning with 3 machines

Tags: constrained-optimization

together!

First of all, I have to mention that because of my background as an Industrial Engineer, I have limited abilities in mathematics, but am disciplined enough to expand myself from competencies.
I am working in a production plant in the production planning. The manufacturing process is divided into 6 steps, but I only control the first. That means I am responsible for the order start. Our planning is currently based on Excel. Per product code, we check each week what the need is for the next two weeks. The possible capacities are then distributed according to the requirements.

There is a great challenge here.
We have three machines, which tend to be able to produce only a certain product portfolio. This means:
Machine 1 can produce 40% of the products.
Machine 2 can produce 50% of the products.
Machine 3 can produce 60% of the products.
This also means that we can not produce every product code every week and have to prioritize accordingly. This is done so far only after our feeling. Here we would like to create a rule.

Actually, the product portfolio or the variance results from two parameters:
The thickness of the product itself, as well as the size of the hole. The machines are drills. They grasp the product with pliers and drill it.
Not every machine can reach any parameter. That means there are the first ruins here.
The products are already ordered in classes, which are assigned according to the thickness. Here we can roughly say what needs to be served per class every two months.

How can an optimal sequence planning be determined for three machines, each of which can only produce a certain product portfolio, and the individual needs differ per product class.

I am grateful for every tip, approach, concept. Like to name just a few keywords or literature, so I can deepen myself.
So far I could only identify the simplex method and the Johnson algorithm as a potential approach. If you need further information, please let me know!

greeting
Joshua

Comment: I have some thoughts but here are some questions first: (1) You are saying that the percentage of products a machine can produce are dependent essentially on what the products thickness and hole size need to be, right? (2) What do you mean the products are ordered in classes? And what do you mean you can say what needs to be served per class? (3) By product code, you mean a specific product represented by that code, right? (4) Does each product take the same amount of time to produce or does this differ depending on the machine and/or product?

Comment: Hey spektr
(1)Exactly, the two parameters of thickness and hole size determine which machine the product can make. For example, machine 1 can only make products with a thickness of 2cm and a 0.5cm hole. Machine 2 can produce products with 2cm thickness and a hole from 0.6cm.
(2) It is not directly classes, but rather groups of a corresponding thickness and hole size, in order to determine / assign the necessary machines. Example:Group1:All 2cm products. Group2: all 3cm products
3)Exactly, each code represents a unique product.
4) Theoretically yes,o nly the conversions are different.

Comment: Is it possible to show an example schedule of some sort with the constraints annotated?